# WSP and SPWebTemplate in CA

Tags: site-template, solution-package

I deployed a wsp solution to SharePoint which adds a new web template to the list of available templates.

The template shows up when I do Get-SPWebTemplate so I'm able to create a new site collection using this template by PowerShell.

From within the site colletion, I'm able to create a new sub-site collection using this template and doing so via GUI.

My problem is that this custom template doesn't show up in CA.

Any ideas why ?

Thanks in advance for your response.

P.-S.: Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Site Templates do not appear in Central Administration. Instead, you click on the Custom tab and create your Site Collection. From there, it will prompt for the template you want to use after the Site Collection has been created.